# Multiple phrases with SpeechRecognition in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

I have posted the complete code below and I would like to be able to achieve repeated execution of `audio = r.listen(source)`. I have gotten the code to repeat but it returns the same thing everytime. I don't really like giving up and coming here asking for answers (first time posting). What do I have to do to get the code to return new phrase every time It executes the `do_again(quit)` function. Basically, the program asks to say something and it works fine the first time. When I am prompted to continue or quit and I enter 'c' I want to repeat the whole thing all over. Any help would be greatly appreciated. PS I am new to python and am probably doing this completely wrong. Any tips also will be appreciated!

Here is the code (All criticism is welcome. like: is there a better cleaner way to do this?)

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()

with m as source:
    print('Speak clearly for better results ...')
    audio = r.listen(source)

quit = 'c'
q = quit

def do_again(quit):
    quit = input('Press c to continue OR press q to quit: ')
    q = quit
    if q == 'q':
        print('Exiting program')
        sys.exit()
    elif q == 'c':
        print('Running again...')

    else:
        print('ERROR! Press c to continue OR press q to quit ')
        return q

response = {"success": True,
            "error": None,
            "transcription": None
}

while q == 'c':
    try:
        # I want this to return new phrase instead of returning the same phrase.
        response['transcription'] = r.recognize_sphinx(audio) # I want a new 'response' here
        print(f"[SPEECH RECOGNIZED] {response['transcription']}")

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print(f"[FATAL ERROR] Exiting...")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        response['success'] = False
        response['error'] = 'API Unavailable/unresponsive'
        print(f"[FATAL ERROR] {response['error']} {e}")
    do_again(quit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer. I was reading the documentation in the python interpreter with the `help(r.Recognizer)` feature. I found a `listen_in_background` method. Will `listen_in_background` do what I need? I know it's a silly program but I plan to do something practical for myself. If this will work, you guys can close this thread. I feel very dumb  haha. I'm gonna try it out and if it works ill post my solution. Thanks again!

[EDIT]
It worked! I defined this function: `def callback(r,audio)` which is needed for `stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)`. I am having a hard time understanding the purpose of this line: `stop_listening(wait_for_stop=True)`. If someone can please explain a bit so I can use it better in the future. Finally i added a 'magic word' to quit the program (just say 'quit' and `sys.quit()` terminates the program.). Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the new code:

```
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
import sys

def callback(r, audio):
    global done
    try:
        print(f"[PocketSphinx]: Thinks you said: '{r.recognize_sphinx(audio)}'. Read some more ")
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print(f"[PocketSphinx]: Fatal error! Unknown Value Error! Exiting program.")
    except sr.RequestError as ex:
        print(f"[PocketSphinx]: Fatal error! Could not process request! {ex}")
    if r.recognize_sphinx(audio) == 'quit':
        print(f"[PocketSphinx]: You said the magic word: 'quit'... Exiting program.")
        done = True

r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 4000
m = sr.Microphone()
done = False
with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

print(f"[PocketSphinx]: Read to me... Say 'quit' to exit...")
stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

# 5 second delay 
for _ in range(50):
    time.sleep(0.1)

while not done:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    if done:
        stop_listening(wait_for_stop=True)
        sys.exit()
```